# Check if a private preference has been created?

Tags: android, xml, preference

I want to check if a xml file exists. The xml is the private preference of an activity. And I want to read from my main activity when app starts. How can I check it?

I don't need read the file, only to know if exists or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check with the help of this, It seems that it's not good solution but you can check your shared prefrence's file.

```
File f = new File("/data/data/"+context.getPackageName()+"/shared_prefs"+"/MyFile.xml");
if(f.exists()){
    Log.v("LOG", "Exist");
}else{
    Log.v("LOG", " Not Exist");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Preference files are saved in

```
/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PREFS_NAME.xml
```